# Return Pandas dataframe rows where more than N columns have the same value

Tags: python, pandas, row, subset

Let's say I have the following dataframe `df`. How can I take in a value N and return only rows where N columns have the same value? For example if N=3, it would return rows 0,2,3,4. If N=4, then only row 3.

```
      'A'   'B'   'C'  'D'   'E'

0      1     1     1    3     5
1      5     4     2    1     2
2      3     4     3    2     3
3      5     5     5    4     5
4      1     2     1    2     1
```

I've found answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21231478/get-rows-that-have-the-same-value-across-its-columns-in-pandas) that are for cases when all values are the same, but can't think of a clean way to adapt it for when it wants an arbitrary number of columns to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can using `value_counts`, ge mean >=, you can change number 3 in it to what you need

```
df[df.apply(pd.value_counts,1).ge(3).any(1)]
Out[257]: 
   'A'  'B'  'C'  'D'  'E'
0    1    1    1    3    5
2    3    4    3    2    3
3    5    5    5    4    5
4    1    2    1    2    1
```